# Django AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute <field>

Tags: python, django

I've got 4 related models in one app:

```
class AssetType(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type_name = CaseInsUniqueCharField(name='Type Name')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='parent')
    type_field = models.ManyToManyField('AssetField', blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    # Return Asset Name for Queries
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_name

class AssetField(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field_name = CaseInsUniqueCharField(name='Field Name')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    # Return Field Name for Queries
    def __str__(self):
        return self.field_name

class AssetFieldValue(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    value = models.CharField('value', blank=True, max_length=100)
    field = models.ForeignKey('AssetField', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    asset = models.ForeignKey('Asset', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    # Return '<Asset> - <Value>' for Queries
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.asset) + "-" + str(self.field) 

class Asset(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asset_type = models.ForeignKey('AssetType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Type')
    asset_name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    asset_tag_no = models.CharField('Tag Number', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    asset_manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('AssetManufacturer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    asset_storage_location = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    asset_list_price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('List Price', blank=True, null=True)
    asset_needs_pat = models.BooleanField('Needs Electrical Test', null=True)
    asset_fields = models.ManyToManyField('AssetField', blank=True, editable=False)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    # Return Asset name for queries
    def __str__(self):
        return self.asset_name
```

And I have added in a post-save handler just under the `Asset` Class

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=Asset)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    t = Asset.asset_type
    f = t.type_field.all()
    for i in range(1,f.count()+1):
        Asset.asset_fields.add(f[i-1:i])
```

That is supposed to add the `AssetFields` records that are related to the Asset's `AssetType`. When I run the following in the django shell I am able to successfully add the relationships to the Asset ManyToMany field `asset_fields`

```
>>> a = Asset.objects.first()
>>> t = a.asset_type
>>> f = t.type_field.all()
>>> for i in range(1, f.count()+1):
...     a.asset_fields.add(f[i-1:i][0])
```

**However when I save an asset, with the same type `t` as used in the shell, through the admin page I get the error:**

```
    AttributeError at /admin/assets/asset/add/
'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'type_field'
```

I'm not sure where this error is coming from as the same functions ran in the shell without any issues, unless potentially I'm dealing with the `@reciever` wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But you don't do the same thing in the view as you do in the shell. In the shell, you access `asset_type` on a specific instance of Asset. In the view, you call it on the *class* itself. That doesn't make sense; as with the shell version, you need to query or create an instance, then you can access its `asset_type` - and call `asset_fields.add()`.

I suspect, since this is a signal handler on Asset, you actually wanted to use the instance that is being saved. In which case:

```
def my_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    t = instance.asset_type
    f = t.type_field.all()
```

I also can't understand what your loop is doing there. I suspect you mean:

```
    for type in t.type_field.all()
        instance.asset_fields.add(t)
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the help - adding `instance` solved the main issue. Your loop is much more elegent than mine, though I assume it's meant to read `instance.asset_fields.add(type)`. Thanks a lot!